# please suggest a 2d games / physics engine for Android

Tags: android

I'm looking forward to make a 2d game for android and was wondering what's the best engine around today?

Basically what I need is to be able to define solid physical objects, like ground or some obstacles, and some character objects that would be able to move around, bump into things, collide, etc.

From what I found so far, andengine.org seems to be the most popular one, what do you think of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cocos2d-x good for IOS + Android both.. :)
Check http://cocos2d-x.org/ for more info..

Comment: If I'm correct, cocos2d-x would need knowledge of C++? :( Maybe then cocos2d-andoid would do better, as it's all java?

Comment: If you know Cocos2d for iPhone.. You can easily work on that.. Its just a matter of knowing framework well. Methods are simpler to use and execute..